# Bash: dynamically assigning array to a new variable

Tags: bash

I have two arrays which I would like to dynamically assign to a variable depending on user input

```
ARRAY_ONE=('one' 'two')
ARRAY_TWO=('three' 'four')
```

Suppose that `$opt` can be either `ONE` or `TWO` depending on user input. I have a variable `ARRAY_THREE` that I would like to assign to the content of either `ARRAY_ONE` or `ARRAY_TWO` depending on the value of `$opt`.

The following snippet does not work, as it only takes the element in the first position of the assigned array:

```
TEMP=ARRAY_$opt
ARRAY_THREE=${!TEMP}
echo $ARRAY_THREE     # 'one'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
TEMP=ARRAY_$opt[@]
ARRAY_THREE=(${!TEMP})
echo ${ARRAY_THREE[@]}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
three four
```

**EDIT:**

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/hocG24

Comment: @perreal: Pls check the linked demo.

Comment: @perreal: Edited the demo to add `echo ${ARRAY_THREE[0]}` and `echo ${ARRAY_THREE[1]}`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ opt=ONE
$ TEMP="ARRAY_${opt}[@]"
$ ARRAY_THREE=( "${!TEMP}" )
$ set|grep ^ARRAY_
ARRAY_ONE=([0]="one" [1]="two")
ARRAY_THREE=([0]="one" [1]="two")
ARRAY_TWO=([0]="three" [1]="four")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that does not use a temp variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo_1=(fff ddd) ;
foo_2=(ggg ccc) ;

for i in 1 2 ;
do
    eval mine=( \${foo_$i[@]} ) ;
    echo ${mine[@]} ;
done ;
```